# Issue with numerical integration

Tags: python, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am currently stuck on a really simple mistake hidden somewhere, and hopefully someone can shine some light on it.

I am trying to numerically integrate a set of data with the conventional methods, and obtaining results that I didn't quite expect.

I then went back to first principles and produced the following code. For some reason I cannot produce y3 or y4 to match y2.

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

f1 = 'x**2 - 1' # Starting function
start, stop, step = -2, 2, 21

x = np.linspace(start, stop, step)
xdash = []
xDoubleDash = []

y1 = eval(f1)
y2 = [] # integrated function
y3 = [] # box rule
y4 = [] # trapezium rule
y5 = [] # numerical differentialtion of integrated function

for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    xdashElement = (x[i] + x[i+1])/2
    y2.append((math.pow(xdashElement,3)/3) - xdashElement) # Integrated Function: (x**3)/3 - x
    xdash.append(xdashElement)
    y3.append((y1[i]+y1[i+1])/2 * abs(((x[i] - x[i+1])))) # box rule
    y4.append(((y1[i]+y1[i+1]) * abs(x[i] - x[i+1]))/2) # trapezium rule

for i in range(0,len(y2)-1):
    xDoubleDashElement = (xdash[i] + xdash[i+1])/2
    xDoubleDash.append(xDoubleDashElement)
    y5.append((y2[i+1]-y2[i])/(xdash[i+1] - xdash[i])) 


plt.plot(x, y1, 'b-')
plt.plot(xdash, y2, 'r-')
plt.plot(xdash, y3, 'g-')
plt.plot(xdash, y4, 'm-')
plt.plot(xDoubleDash, y5, 'c-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have added y5, a numerical differentiation of y2 as a sanity check.

Comment: What results did you get, what did you expect, and why did you expect whatever you expected?

Comment: Your y2 doesn't seem to be a definite integral from the same starting point as y3 and y4. It looks like a definite integral starting at 0, or an indefinite integral with C naively set to 0.

Comment: Actually, your y3 and y4 aren't even definite integrals; they're the individual bits you'd sum together in numeric definite integration.

Comment: off-topics, but: `f1 = 'x**2 - 1'; y1 = eval(f1)` -- please don't do this. just write a function or simply write `y1 = x**2 - 1`

Comment: I have added y5, a numerical differentiation of y2 as a sanity check. I understand y2 is an indefinite integral of y1, and both y3 and y4 are definite integrals computed along the range. I was expecting the values of y3 and y4 to closely resemble that of y2, and would theoretically match if the increment x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small, by the theoretical definition of the integral

Comment: @PaulH Yeah this was quickly copied and pasted from an online example, it has shown to work for this quick test case so didn't bother with it too much

Answer (score 0):

Your `y2` is an indefinite integral, while your `y3` and `y4` are definite integral over a series of interval. I won't expect they match each other. If you want to check your numerical integration with an antiderivative, your `y3` and `y4` should match this `y2`:

```
ya = (math.pow(x[i],3)/3) - x[i]
yb = (math.pow(x[i+1],3)/3) - x[i+1]
y2.append(yb-ya) # Integrated Function: (x**3)/3 - x
```

## Edit in response to comments on [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral):

> I was expecting the values of y3 and y4 to closely resemble that of y2, and would theoretically match if the increment x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small, by the theoretical definition of the integral

Based on [this definition of integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral),

[image: \int_a^b ! f(x)dx]

where *F* is the antiderivative or the indefinite integral of *f*.

For your `y3` or `y4`, at `x=(x[i] + x[i+1])/2` you have y:

[image: f((x[i] + x[i+1])/2) ~= F(x[i+1]) - F(x[i])]

For your `y2`, at `x=(x[i] + x[i+1])/2` you have y:

[image: f((x[i] + x[i+1])/2) = F((x[i] + x[i+1])/2)]

When "x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small", you would have

[image: F((x[i] + x[i+1])/2) ~= F(x[i]) ~= F(x[i+1])]

[image: F(x[i+1]) - F(x[i]) ~= 0]

In other words, when "x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small", your `y3` or `y4` are almost a horizontal line at `y=0`. Why should your `y2` matches a line at `y=0`?

If you really want to see your `y3` and `y4` match the shape of `y2`, you would need a `y0` or "[arbitrary constant of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_constant_of_integration)" to get start and make `y3` and `y4` like this:

```
y0 = -.7
y3 = [y0] # box rule
y4 = [y0] # trapezium rule
for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    xdashElement = (x[i] + x[i+1])/2
    y3.append((y1[i]+y1[i+1])/2 * abs(((x[i] - x[i+1]))) + y3[len(y3) - 1]) # box rule
    y4.append(((y1[i]+y1[i+1]) * abs(x[i] - x[i+1]))/2 + y4[len(y4) - 1]) # trapezium rule
y3.pop(0)
y4.pop(0)
```

Then with an increase of your `step` or "the increment x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small", these `y3` and `y4` will match `y2`.

Comment: I have added y5, a numerical differentiation of y2 as a sanity check. I understand y2 is an indefinite integral of y1, and both y3 and y4 are definite integrals computed along the range. I was expecting the values of y3 and y4 to closely resemble that of y2, and would theoretically match if the increment x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small, by the theoretical definition of the integral

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. What is the theorem which makes you conclude `y3` and `y4` would " theoretically match" `y2` "if the increment x[i+1] - x[i] becomes infinitely small"? Or what is your "theoretical definition of the integral"? I'll update my logic in my answer. Could you please check if it's convincing?

Comment: Well, this is what I am referring to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral)
Please correct me if I am wrong, as I understand it, the value obtained from numerical integration in each interval along the x axis should resemble the value of the indefinite integral function at that point of x.

Comment: Finished the updates to my answer. Could you please check it and let me know if I missed something in the logic and/or in your question?

Comment: Also update with a new `y3` and `y4` which indeed match the shape of `y2`. If you don't mind, please also check that.

Comment: It worked thanks, that's the part of the definition I overlooked